# I am trying to get the user input in python

Tags: python-3.x

This is my code but I am getting an error while compiling in python.

### Code

```
print ("Enter the height :")
feet = int(input("feet:"))
```

### Error

> ```
> Enter the height :
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "main.py", line 2, in <module>
>     feet = int(raw_input("feet:"))
> ```
>
> NameError: name 'raw_input' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

`raw_input` is no longer a part of python 3.x

You can use

```
feet = int(input("Enter height in feet: "))

print(feet)
```

Comment: I have no error when I run it. You must be doing something else.

Comment: i am using an compiler of python 3.6 provided by my college and in that i am getting the error

Comment: print ("Enter the height :")
person_feet = int(input("feet :"))
person_inch1 = int(input("inch :"))
person_inch2 = (person_feet * 12) + person_inch1
person_cm = 2.54 * person_inch2
print("the height of the person in cm is %d cm." % person_cm)

Comment: I'm still not receiving an error. Can you post the traceback

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):